# Limit number of emails per time from Log4j2 SMTPAppender

Tags: java, log4j2

I use [Apache Log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) and its `SMTPAppender` in an application. It's configured to send email notifications for events of level `ERROR` or above. Usually this works great.

But recently I had a batch processing situation in which thousands of `ERROR` lines were logged in a time interval of 5 minutes. My inbox was flooded with thousands of emails and our mail server blacklisted the affected application server...

To avoid such a mishap: Can we apply a maximum limit to the number of emails sent per time interval?

E.g. I'd like `SMTPAppender` to **not send more than 20 emails per hour**. If this limit is exceeded, further `ERROR`/`FATAL` lines should be aggregated into a single email which is sent as soon as one more email may be sent regarding the limit of 20/hour.

Is there a Log4j2-standard way to achieve that? How did you solve this task in your apps using Log4j2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`BurstFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#BurstFilter). These are the parameters (from the documentation):

| Parameter Name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| level | String | Level of messages to be filtered. Anything at or below this level will be filtered out if maxBurst has been exceeded. The default is WARN meaning any messages that are higher than warn will be logged regardless of the size of a burst. |
| rate | float | The average number of events per second to allow. |
| maxBurst | integer | The maximum number of events that can occur before events are filtered for exceeding the average rate. The default is 10 times the rate. |
| onMatch | String | Action to take when the filter matches. May be ACCEPT, DENY or NEUTRAL. The default value is NEUTRAL. |
| onMismatch | String | Action to take when the filter does not match. May be ACCEPT, DENY or NEUTRAL. The default value is DENY. |

```xml
<Appenders>
   <SMTP> <!-- parameters omitted for brevity -->
      <BurstFilter level="ERROR" rate="16" maxBurst="100"/>
   </SMTP>
</Appenders>
```

Comment: It sounds like this can only limit how many emails are sent in one second. Can it also limit how many emails are received in an hour. Even if it lets you set rate to a fraction, how often does it reset? If it stops a burst, does it reset and allow another burst the very next second? 

There was an extender for a previous version of log4j at https://www.codereye.com/2009/03/sending-email-alerts-with-log4j.html, but it no longer works in log4j2.